# What data structure to use and algorithm to use for searching value?

Tags: database, algorithm, set, computer-science

There is identified entities with unique id.
It could be any entity from real life, for example car, color, red .etc.
I place entity id in set. So, set can contains a lot of id's.

The set should provide a fast reading by id.

My question is which algorith to choose for reading entity by id and what is  structure of data to use?

Is there any tools as permament database, because I need to store sets long time with ability of recovery after crash?

Comment: Have a hashing algorithm for constant lookup times. Use one of the tens of dbs out there that are capable of this. Otherwise, the question is too broad to give useful/thoughtful answers. IMO.

Comment: What about elastic search?

Comment: elastic search is well known for its full text search capabilities. you say you have **unique** identifiers. If there is such a guarantee and if you are going to lookup data using those identifiers and also don't care about ordering (both ordering of the keys and insertion order) hashing is the way to go. You could use an in memory key value db with persistence like Redis.